# Question related to table() function in r

Tags: r

I have a very big dataset where there are a number of repetitions of suppose the state column for all latitude and longitude that it covers. Now, I want to find the order in which these states appear (data frame is too big so doesn't show all names) so as to add another column of values in the correct order corresponding to state names. The inner_join doesn't work and says that cannot assign variable of size 122.3Gb. I wanted to use the table() function but it gives alphabetically sorted values and not the order in which the state names appear in the data frame. What can I do?

Comment: `unique(df$state)` should return a vector of the states in the order in which they appear in your dataset.  I'm not entirely sure what you were trying to do with the inner_join you mentioned, so I'm not sure how to help with that bit.

Comment: You should really have a reproducible example. It sounds like you want to do ```mutate(df, state_order = order(state))```